# Scala error: '=' expected but ';' found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Not sure what caused this problem: error: '=' expected but ';' found.

```
val vectors = filtered_data_by_key.map( x => {
    var temp
    x._2.copyToArray(temp)  // Error occurs here
    (x._1, temp)
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`var temp` isn't a statement.

If you're trying to declare temp without assigning anything to it, do

```
var temp :Array[_] = _
```

But is temp supposed to be an array? then try `var temp = Array()`. `temp` needs something assigned to it before being passed into `copyToArray`. Also as you're not destructively assigning to temp it doesn't need to be a var.

Comment: after I use var temp = _, got error: unbound placeholder parameter

Comment: temp is supposed to be Array(AnyVal)

Comment: what type is temp supposed to be?

Comment: I think you mean `Array[AnyVal]`. You need to instantiate `temp` before passing it into `copyToArray`, so try `val temp = Array[AnyVal]()`

Comment: thank you, it is working now. I am from machine learning, and very new to spark. do you have any recommendations about how to start learning spark and scala systematically? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If filtered_data_by_key is an RDD of (T, Iterable), or in other words, a result of groupByKey transformation, then this can be written simply like this:

```
val vectors = filtered_data_by_key.map( { case (x, iter) => (x, iter.toArray) })
```